# Execution time of C++ algorithm

Tags: c++

If i know that 0,00096 ms is average search time in a map with 290 024 element in c++
How can i go about to calculate the search time for a map with 1 000 000 element?

I know that search algorithm has complexity O(Log N) for map and O(1) for Unordered_map.

It complexity had been linear than I could just multiply the time with 1000 000/290024

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I want to know how people calculate execution time for large nbr when they know execution time for a small nbr.
In the linear case it was easy like i said.
But how can i do the same if Its O(logN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a logarithmic search, the time would be

```
T ~= constant * log(N)
T / log(N) ~= constant
```

So to estimate the time `T2` for size `N2` given time `T1` for size `N1`:

```
T2 / log(N2) ~= T1 / log(N1)
T2 ~= T1 * log(N2) / log(N1)
   ~= 0.00096ms * log(1000000) / log(290024)
   ~= 0.00105ms
```

For a constant-time hash lookup, the time won't change. In practice, it probably won't quite be constant-time; but there's no simple way to estimate what it will be.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? I believe this answers the question, but please correct me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Linear - O(N), not O(1) or O(Log N). If you are using hash map search time should be approximately the same for 290 024 and 1000 000. Concrete results depends on algorithm implementation details.